# Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'jquery-ui'? with jquery-ui-rails(4.1.2)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery-ui-rails gem with 4.1.2 version. I get this above mentioned error when I try to load my home page. I cannot use any higher version in jquery-ui-rails as it depends on Railties (3.2.16) and gems in my gem file needs railties (3.1.*). Can someone help me solve this issue.

this is my application.js file

```
//= require jquery.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//=require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//=require jquery.multiselect.min


//= require_tree .
```

application.css file

```
 *= require 0reset
 *= require base

 *= require buttons
 *= require margin
 *= require padding
 *= require panel
 *= require styles
 *= require tables
 *= require ui
 *= require ra-ui
 *= require_self

*=require jquery.ui.all
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
  *= require jquery.multiselect


 *= require_tree .
```

Gem file:

```
gem 'rake', '10.4.2'
gem 'sinatra-flash', :require => 'sinatra/flash'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'rubyzip'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'rdoc'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.1.1.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.15.35'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
gem 'rails'
gem 'sc-ui-core'
gem 'decimal-money'
gem 'chosen-rails'
```

Comment: can you show the application.js file

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: can you try with `*= require jquery-ui`  in application.css

Comment: I have already included that in css file. updated css file as well in the question.

Comment: did you try updated answer?

Answer (score 1):

Add following code into your **application.js** file

```
//= require jquery-ui
```

**application.css**

```
*= require jquery-ui
```

If you are using version  **<5.0** use

```
//= require jquery.ui.all

*= require jquery.ui.all
```

respectively.

Comment: I have tried the above fix. It gives me following error:

NoMethodError - undefined method `font_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fabd74ab7a0>:0x007fabd2ddd148>
  (in /campaign-manager-console/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.scss):

I am updating my gem file in the question.

Comment: check your app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss file for "bootstrap-spockets",comment it out and try. make sure you added required code https://github.com/joliss/jquery-ui-rails/blob/v4.2.1/README.md

Comment: I have application.css file in my app/assets/stylesheets/ path, in which I have not included bootstrap-sprockets.

I have my js and css files as mentioned in the question. I have included jquery.ui.all in both the files. Not sure what else is needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having a problem with this.

- Download jquery-ui from [jquery](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js)
- Move it to your app/assets/javascripts/jquery-ui.js
- rake assets:precompile